# Why is my React component beneath the overlay?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

i have a component that have two children, one overlay and the Google Maps component. I have markers in the map and when I click on it, I want it to open a tooltip and apply a black overlay all over the map. The tooptip should be above it. How can i achieve it? Here's what i tried so far

### Main Component

```
  return (
    <section className="h-svh w-full">
      <MapOverlay />
      <GoogleMap
        apiKey={key}
        defaultZoom={15}
        onGoogleApiLoaded={onGoogleApiLoaded}
        defaultCenter={{
          lat: defaultCenter!.latitude,
          lng: defaultCenter!.longitude,
        }}
      >
        {orders.map((e) => (
          <DriverMarker
            key={e.id}
            lat={defaultCenter!.latitude}
            lng={defaultCenter!.longitude}
            order={e}
          />
        ))}
      </GoogleMap>
    </section>
  );
```

### Overlay Component

```
export function MapOverlay() {
  const [active, setActive] = useActiveOrder((s) => [s.active, s.setActive]);

  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => active && setActive(false)}
      className={`fixed top-0 left-0 h-svh w-full  ${
        active ? "bg-stone-800 bg-opacity-25 z-20" : ""
      }`}
    ></div>
  );
}
```

### Marker Component

```
  return (
    <div
      className="relative bg-pink-500 z-[9999] h-40 w-40"
      onClick={onClick}
    ></div>
  );
```

The overlay works fine, but nothing gets on top of it